# It is saying that mean, and median when chosen, is not defined?

Tags: python

```
def average(vals, method):
    if method == mean:
        mean == (sum(a)/len(a))
    print('The mean is', str(mean))
    if method == median:
        median == (len(a)-1)//2
    print('The median is', str(median))

average((-1,0,1,1,1,2,3), mean)
```

I dont understand what needs fixing, can anyone help?

Comment: in the line `average((-1,0,1,1,1,2,3), mean)` the variable `mean` is in fact not defined anywhere in scope. What value did you *expect* `mean` to have? I think you are confusing *variables* with strings.

Comment: How would you define the mean then, sorry I am pretty new to coding.

Comment: The same way you define any variable. But the point is, I don't think you want to define a variable at all.

Comment: Why would I not want to define a variable?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say `if method == 'mean'`?  i.e. an actual string "mean", not some variable named mean.

Comment: When I do that I still get the same problem.

Comment: I also think you meant to say `mean = (sum(a)/len(a))` with one equal sign instead of two.  Same with `median == `.  To _assign_ a variable, use one equal sign.  Otherwise if you use two equal signs, that is a _comparison_, not an _assignment_.

Comment: Also, indent the two `print` statements to be underneath the `if` statements.  You only want to print the mean if that's what the method is.

Comment: Also also, you're not calculating the median correctly.  `median` is actually the _list index_ where the median value is located, not the median value itself.

Comment: Ok thank you but it's still saying mean is not defined.

Comment: That's probably because on the very bottom line, you need to change it to `average((-1,0,1,1,1,2,3), "mean")`

Comment: Of course this is all assuming that you really did intend `mean` to be an actual string value instead of a variable.  If I'm wrong about that, you can throw out most of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some fixed code:

```
def average(vals, method):
    if method == 'mean':
        mean = (sum(a)/len(a))
        print('The mean is', mean)
    if method == 'median':
        midpoint = (len(a)-1)//2
        median = vals[midpoint]
    print('The median is', median)

average((-1,0,1,1,1,2,3), 'mean')
average((-1,0,1,1,1,2,3), 'median')
```